# android studio 1.0.2 - proguard and rules file location

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, proguard

I imported a project from eclipse and now I want to add its proguard-rules.txt files. This is how the app structure looks like:

[image: structure]

I saw other places where build.gradle files were located differently, how can I do it?

Where and how can I add the proguard-rules.txt file?

How can I make sure that proguard is actually affecting the APK (in eclipse it generated several txt files)?

Answer (score 0):

Did you look at: `File -> Project Structure -> (module_name) under Modules -> Flavors -> Proguard File` in Android Studio?

Comment: I did now but it seems to keep erasing the file path I add there to the proguard rules files even though I click OK

Answer (score 0):

See in `"projectfolder"/module_name/proguard-rules.txt`

In your case `"projectfolder"/app/proguard-rules.txt`

At the same time it is not created automatically. You can create it manually.